# Plotting a line over 'histogram-like' bins

Tags: pgfplots, line, histogram

I have to convert the following JPEG image into a TeX-equivilant diagram using tikz and pgfplots.

[image: JPEG image that I want to integrate into my tex document]

This is what I have sofar:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\linewidth,
                height=8cm,
                ymin=0,
                ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
                ymax=100,
                ylabel={Percentage},
                symbolic x coords={0-15,15-59,60-64,65-69,70-74,75-79,80-84,85-89,90+},
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords align={vertical}
                ]
                \addplot[draw={rgb:red,36;green,105;blue,179},ultra thick, smooth, nodes near coords] 
                    coordinates {(0-15,0.7) (15-59,0.6) (60-64,1.9) (65-69,3.0) (70-74,5.0) (75-79,9.8) (80-84,21.0) (85-89,38.2) (90+,64.4)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image]

The graph almost resembles the aforementioned JPEG image. However I am having problems with the following:

A. How do I draw vertical lines between the bins as seen in the first JPEG Image?

B. How do I remove the x and y axes ticks as seen in my TeX Graph?

C. How do I visualize the big blue dots at the numbered value as seen in the first JPEG Image?

D. How do I shift the visualized numbers at the coords slightly upwards so that they do not interfere with the drawn line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B. Use option `tick style={draw=none}`.

A. For the gray lines use a grid at minor ticks:

```
minor x tick num=1,
minor ytick={10,30,90},
grid=minor,
```

C. Use option `mark*` for the plot and change `draw` to `color`.

```
\addplot[color={rgb:red,36;green,105;blue,179},mark=*,...] ...
```

D. Use option `nodes near coords style` to shift the numbers and change the color back to black:

```
nodes near coords style={yshift=1em,black},
```

Additionally I would use a smaller font size.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=\linewidth,
      height=8cm,
      ymin=0,
      ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
      ymax=100,
      ylabel={Percentage},
      symbolic x coords={0-15,15-59,60-64,65-69,70-74,75-79,80-84,85-89,90+},
      xtick=data,
      font=\footnotesize,
      tick style={draw=none},
      minor x tick num=1,
      minor ytick={10,30,90},
      grid=minor,
      nodes near coords style={yshift=1em,black},
      ]
      \addplot[color={rgb:red,36;green,105;blue,179},mark=*,ultra thick, smooth, nodes near coords] 
        coordinates {(0-15,0.7) (15-59,0.6) (60-64,1.9) (65-69,3.0) (70-74,5.0) (75-79,9.8) (80-84,21.0) (85-89,38.2) (90+,64.4)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for B `draw=none` is better

Comment: @percusse Ok, I have changed this.